# Javascript to understand standard form?

Tags: javascript, math

What I am trying to do is this, this user will input a string of binary which will be divided by 360 have it rounded down then have it's remainder recorded as well, as a form of compression, giving the user 2 small strings instead of a 100 digit long string. However, problems arise when I give it a standard form input to decompress (i.e. 222e^-18). The way that I compress the string is as follows;

```
function getInput(){ 
prompt('Input');
} var userInput = prompt('Input');

var compressedInput = userInput / 360;

var compressedDivision = Math.floor(compressedInput)

var compressedRemainder = userInput % 360;

console.log(compressedDivision)
console.log(compressedRemainder)
```

And the code to decompress the string is below;

```
function decompressFn(){
    prompt('Division')
    prompt('Remainder')
}

var divisionDecompress = prompt('Division');
var remainderDecompress = prompt('Remainder');

var divisionOutput = divisionDecompress * 360;
var decompressedOutput = divisionOutput + remainderDecompress;

console.log(decompressedOutput)
```

Now, If you are to give a string into the input for the first bit of code such as what follows;

*010011000110111101110010011001010111001001101101001000000100100101110000011100110111010101101101001000000110010001101111011011000110111101110010001000000110010101110100*

(Lorem Ipsum dolor et)

You will get two outputs, the rounded division and the remainder. But these however will be in standard form so if you were to enter these into the two prompts for the decompression script, you'd get this;

*1.0011000110111101e+1660*

which if plugged into a online scientific calculator, seems to be infinite! So my question is as the title implies, how do you get JavaScript to understand standard form, or is there something up with my code?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand what you are trying to achieve, but keep in mind that JavaScript can only represent integers up to `2^53` precisely, i.e. 52 bit integers. Furthermore, if the input is `01001100011011...` then JS will interpret that number as octal value.

Comment: So is there a way around this? plus what's up with it outputting an infinite num... output?

Comment: Around what? Maybe you are looking for a BigInt library? Google should help with that. There is also one called strint.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are dealing with numbers (because you can't do arithmetic with strings; JavaScript will auto-convert your strings from `prompt` into numbers for the calculation).

JavaScript numbers have a finite range (1.7976931348623157e+308, that's 1 and 308 zeroes after it) and a finite precision (15 digits or so). The biggest integer you can represent is 9007199254740991. Any time you go over the precision limit, you get errors in calculation, as your numbers only become approximations of what you really input. Anything that is over the range limit is infinity, as far as JavaScript is concerned.

Furthermore, you are inputting binary numbers (`01001100`) as if they were decimal. The radix is purely a matter of input and output; numbers don't have radices, their *representations* do. Thus, if you want the user to interact in binary, you will have to convert the input strings to numbers (explicitly this time) before you let computer at the input; and you will have to have to convert the results in the other direction, into binary strings:

```
var userInput = parseInt(prompt('Input'), 2);
...
console.log(compressedDivision.toString(2))
```

Finally, this is no compression at all: you get two numbers whose length adds up to more or less the same size as the original number. You could say it is an encoding of sorts; but hardly compression.

Comment: Cheers for the answer. And it's compression as it simply adds up how many 360's can fit inside the number, so instead of 1081, you get 3 and 1, compressed. But if I'm getting the definitions wrong then sorry (not meant to be patronising)

Comment: @BenHalford: What I'm saying is that "3 and 1" are a minority occurence. For 1079, you'd be getting 3 and 359. Not sure which edits you meant - I believe the whole answer is basically saying you are doing something that is not really to be done (also, "not working" is a useless report, it's like faxing your passport photo to the doctor with a note "I'm sick, cure me").

Comment: True, but you're still not getting any more digits to deal with after the compression are you? and think in the much larger scales where you have 359,999......... Yeah ok, I understand now!

Comment: Haha, very funny... It's still outputting the wrong answer, this time it's;
1.10110010110101010000011111110001011110011110010001e+157

Comment: That was the passport photo :P What is the code that produced it?

Comment: That is not the output I am getting from your input given in the question and the code you just posted - I get `11011001011010101000001111111000101111001111001000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` and `192`. Also note that the input has about 50 (decimal) digits, of which only 15 are "correct" - as I said in the Answer, JavaScript can't calculate with numbers this big.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I used different binary, but try and decompress that now.

Comment: You did not post any decompression code. And again, it can't be correct, as I explained twice so far. It's like putting an orange into a matchbox: it simply does not fit unless you trim it a bit.

Comment: Ok, then is there another language similar to JavaScript that has a further range or is that just a universal problem with floating point precision?

Comment: Universal problem with floating point precision. However, as hinted by Felix Kling, you can use a bigint library (which basically re-implements math for arbitrary-size integers, often represented by arrays or strings, and is typically slower than floating-point arithmetic). Ruby and Python have bigints seamlessly integrated; JavaScript needs a library. However, I still maintain that this is an XY problem: if you stated what you wanted this *for*, there might be a much more elegant solution.

Comment: I'm making this so that I can compress much larger files (Gigabytes) as small as possible pretty much. More as a side project.

Comment: Like my JavaScript game that I boast about making at every possible interval. Of which you can find at: https://jsfiddle.net/v95fs3ks/38/

Comment: As said above, that will not do much. You can't really do any significant compression using plain arithmetic. Look up Huffman coding and Lempel-Ziv-Welch for relatively easy to implement compression algorithms, if it's just for funsies and education; if for real-life purposes, there are very good existing implementations of compression algorithms that work better than anything you (or I) will ever be able to do by oneself (unless you turn into a math or compsci major, specialising in compression).

Comment: Ok, how do you implement BigInt with javascript?

Comment: That's a bit broad even for a question, let alone a comment; but basically you teach your math skills to the computer. If you are asking how to find a library, see Felix Kling's comment on your Question. If you are really asking how to implement one, reading the source of an existing one would help.